# Dealing with newlines in a chatbot

Tags: dialog, ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

```
Have you seen
people asking questions
to a chatbot 
like it is instant messaging?
```

People are so used to writing in Whatsapp and other instant messaging platforms with a newline after every clause. Watson seems in general takes newline as an entire question to be answered. whereas users can put one message across multiple lines*

Is there a known way to deal with users breaking up questions over multiple lines? You could check if they are still typing and I have some other ideas but I would be interested if anyone has solved this problem before.

*edit

Comment: Is it one message with multiple lines or is it multiple messages?

Comment: With "Watson" you probably mean the chatbot/dialog/conversation examples. The truth is that those code samples just wait for newline and feed the input to Watson. You could extend those examples to wait for a question mark or something else